# integrating leaflet map in RShiny - inputselect by country and symptom

Tags: r, leaflet, shinyapps

I am attempting to create a map within Shiny R, with leaflet. I have several questions:

1. How to create the map by selecting Symptoms by Country? as you can see data contains countries and symptoms in rows (see link on GitHub provided bellow). if I want to filter by a certain country and certain symptom how do I do this with leaflet in Shiny r?
2. I want created a draggable drop down menu (where symptoms can be chosen - see question 1) since I cannot adjust the map on the entire screen. An example of a draggable drop down menu, called 'Zip Explored' I have tried to replicate, with no success is here - https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/superzip-example.html
3. I could not make the map to show on the entire screen. Is there a way to show the map on the entire screen? Just like the example in the web-link on 2nd point.

here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(cvindia)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinydashboard)


server = function(input, output, session){}




    ui <- fluidPage(
    
        # Application title
        h1("Symptoms accross the world"),
    
        # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
        selectInput("productCategory", "Select Country", c( "Bangladesh", "India", "Nigeria", "Pakistan", "United Kingdom")), 
        selectInput("productCategory", "Symptom", c("Chills", "Cough", "Muscle Ache"))
    )
    
    server <- function(input, output) {
        
        
    }
    
    
    # Run the application 
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If the above code is run, then I have easily managed to create the selectInput by country and symptom.

Here is the second code I have which I do not understand how it should interact with the server, having in mind the values I am interested, and presume it should interact with user interface are in the rows:

```
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles()

map <- leaflet(gather_divided) %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers(clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())

map
```

Sample of a dataset is on my GitHub as I haven't found a more elegant way of deploying it to stack overflow:

https://github.com/gabrielburcea/stackoverflow_fake_data/tree/master

Comment: What exactly is your question? Have you read the docs? https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html

Comment: @heds1 -Yes, but honestly it is not clear to me how do I create my map according to my question ( I had made it clearer now). As I am looking into rows rather than columns. Additionally, I am very new in shiny r and hard for me to even understand the concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a brief demo that I hope will be helpful.

A few notes:

- Make sure each `selectInput` has a unique `inputId`. You have the same id for both.
- You may want to add `multiple = TRUE` to `selectInput` to allow for more than one country or symptom to be selected
- You can use a `reactive` expression in `server` to filter the data based on the input selections

This also might be helpful reference for using `leaflet` with `shiny`:

https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html

Let me know if this is what you had in mind.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)

fake_data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gabrielburcea/stackoverflow_fake_data/master/gather_divided.csv")

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  h1("Symptoms accross the world"),
  
  # Inputs for country and symptom 
  selectInput("country", "Select Country", c("Bangladesh", "India", "Nigeria", "Pakistan", "United Kingdom"), multiple = TRUE), 
  selectInput("symptom", "Symptom", c("Chills", "Cough", "Muscle Ache"), multiple = TRUE),
  
  # Output with map
  h2("Map"),
  leafletOutput("map")
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    fake_data %>%
      filter(Country %in% input$country,
             Symptom %in% input$symptom)
  })
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(data = filtered_data())
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Edit**:

To make your `selectInput` appear in a floating, draggable menu, you can use `absolutePanel` (as in the example you referenced).

Note that the example uses custom .css which can improve the appearance of your shiny app further.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  h1("Symptoms accross the world"),
  leafletOutput("map"),
  
  # Floating panel
  absolutePanel(id = "controls", class = "panel panel-default", fixed = TRUE,
                draggable = TRUE, top = 60, left = "auto", right = 20, bottom = "auto",
                width = 330, height = "auto",
                
                h2("Data Explorer"),
                
                # Inputs for country and symptom 
                selectInput("country", "Select Country", c("Bangladesh", "India", "Nigeria", "Pakistan", "United Kingdom"), multiple = TRUE), 
                selectInput("symptom", "Symptom", c("Chills", "Cough", "Muscle Ache"), multiple = TRUE)
  )
)
```

Comment: thank you. I am trying to run your code and it doesn't display the map

Comment: yes, actually I tried yours and it works, yet mine is the issue. May I try to correct mine and then comeback and ask more questions in light of the issue posted?

Comment: thank you so much! It worked! Now I need to seriously read on this, what each function does! Because I am a bit lost with it. But I do see some clear patters. reactive, renderLeaflet, comes into server, whilst the user interface is more of the design!

Comment: is there a way to cut the multiplied map? I mean I want one instance of the world map not too many as leaflet does. And also I want to define the map on the entire page rather then one slice which appears in the middle.

Comment: @GaB I'm not sure I follow --- would you like to edit your question to match what your current app looks like?

Comment: @GaB Thanks, see edited answer. This is one way to get a floating, draggable menu of `selectInput` options. Let me know if this is what you had in mind. The example also uses some custom .css for styling, which you could consider as well.

Comment: I actually tried to use css and wish to do that. Is just that I haven't succeeded. If there is a way you can help with that (I know I've requested so much already - please do not feel the need to do this) I would gladly learn.

Comment: There's a good description of incorporating .css in shiny apps [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html). If you haven't seen this yet, it might be helpful. Alternatively, this could be a good separate question on SO, if you describe further what you've tried so far.

Comment: Also, is there a way to make the map to occupy the whole screen and show me one instance of the world map only? Because, when I zoom out, I get so many instances of the world mapo

Comment: Ben, will add another question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217751/discussion-between-gab-and-ben).