# Got an error when running css with Shiny R

Tags: css, r, shiny

I am trying to run my css file in Shiny R. I have succeed running without css. But I added style.css and it doesn't work. Here is what I have done:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)

fake_data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gabrielburcea/stackoverflow_fake_data/master/gather_divided.csv")




# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    navbarPage("SARS-Covid-19 Symptom Mapper", 
             div(class = "outer", 
                 
                 tabPanel("Interactive map", 
                          div(class = "outer", 
                              
                              tags$head(
                                  # Include our custom CSS
                                  includeCSS("style.css")   
                              ), 
                              
                              leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "95vh"),
                              
                              
                              #Floating panel 
                              absolutePanel(id = "controls", class = "panel panel-default", fixed = TRUE,
                                            draggable = TRUE, top = 60, left = "auto", right = 20, bottom = "auto",
                                            width = 330, height = "auto",
                                            
                                            h2("Select symptom"),
                                            
                                            selectInput("symptom", "Select Symptom", c("Chills",
                                                                                       "Cough", "Diarrhoea",
                                                                                       "Fatigue",
                                                                                       "Headache",
                                                                                       "Loss of smell and taste",
                                                                                       "Muscle ache",
                                                                                       "Nasal congestion",
                                                                                       "Nausea and vomiting",
                                                                                       "Shortness of breath",
                                                                                       "Sore throat",
                                                                                       "Sputum",
                                                                                       "Temperature")
                                            )
                              
                              )
             
             )

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    filtered_data <- reactive({
        fake_data %>% 
            dplyr::filter(Symptom %in% input$symptom)
    })
    
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        
        leaflet() %>%
            addTiles() %>%
            addMarkers(data = filtered_data(), clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())
        
    })
    
}


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This is the error I get:

```
Error in parse(file, keep.source = FALSE, srcfile = src, encoding = enc) : 
  /Users/myname/Rprojects/training_shiny/app.R:53:1: unexpected symbol
52: 
53: server
```

Yet, If I exclude working with css I have no problem in running the app. If you exclude the lines from navbarPage all the way to line leafletOutput, letting the code from leafletOutput onwards, I have no issue running my app.The problem occurs when I am trying to add the style.css . For more details on how I run the app without css press this link: [integrating leaflet map in RShiny - inputselect by country and symptom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62855628/integrating-leaflet-map-in-rshiny-inputselect-by-country-and-symptom/62863015#62863015)

Comment: The style sheet I have is exactly same as the new one you posted. Just in case, I copied the new one and tested it. It still works fine and gives me the first image in my answer. I like that it fades if the `ui` dialog box is in the middle of the graph. As far as I see there should not be an issue. My RStudio is version 1.1.453. That should not be an issue.

Comment: My R Studio is 1.3.156. I do not believe it is because to the R/RStudio version.

Comment: anyway, will open a new issue for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this
whole code, and it uses your style sheet as style2.css

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)

fake_data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gabrielburcea/stackoverflow_fake_data/master/gather_divided.csv")

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  navbarPage("SARS-Covid-19 Symptom Mapper",
             div(class = "outer",
              tabPanel("Interactive map",
                div(class = "outer",
                    tags$head(
                      # Include our custom CSS
                      #includeCSS("style.css")
                      tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "style2.css")
                    ),

                    leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "95vh"),

                    #Floating panel
                    absolutePanel(id = "controls", class = "panel panel-default", fixed = TRUE,
                                  draggable = TRUE, top = 60, left = "auto", right = 20, bottom = "auto",
                                  width = 330, height = "auto",

                                  h2("Select symptom"),

                                  selectInput("symptom", "Select Symptom", c("Chills",
                                                                             "Cough", "Diarrhoea",
                                                                             "Fatigue",
                                                                             "Headache",
                                                                             "Loss of smell and taste",
                                                                             "Muscle ache",
                                                                             "Nasal congestion",
                                                                             "Nausea and vomiting",
                                                                             "Shortness of breath",
                                                                             "Sore throat",
                                                                             "Sputum",
                                                                             "Temperature")
                                  )

                    )

                )
              )))
  )

server <- function(input, output) {
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    fake_data %>%
      dplyr::filter(Symptom %in% input$symptom)
  })
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(data = filtered_data(), clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())
    
  })
  
}

###  Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The following output is with your style sheet:

[image: output1]

This is without your style sheet:

[image: output2]

Comment: Do you still get the same error? I don't get any error. Please ensure that you keep your style.css file in a folder named 'www' under your working directory.

Comment: yes, I get the same error. Can you check running with the style.css file on my GitHub -https://github.com/gabrielburcea/stackoverflow_fake_data/blob/master/style.css

Comment: I have the style.css in the folder www Also, after the code 'tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "style.css"))' I have another bracket followed by a coma.

Comment: Please see the images in the answer above. Not sure why you have errors, and I don't.

Comment: thank you a lot for your effort. Probably it will help me posting the whole code you run. I believe either there is a missing coma somewhere or an addition of breakers. Not sure ,,,

Comment: thank you a lot, it worked. I had missing breakets. The only thing that did not work was the select symptom selector. It shows without css style

Comment: I have updated the post with the remaining probable. Is there you can help me ? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Please rename style2.css in my code to style.css or whatever the style sheet filename is in www folder.

Comment: I kept style.css and it is in www folder

Comment: I have R version 4.0.2 and it may have something to do if you are running in a different version of R. Try `fakedata <- data.frame(fake_data, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    fakedata %>% ...` when you create `filtered_data`.  Also, you should quit and restart RStudio.

Comment: I have followed all your suggestions. I've updated my R. I have transformed data into format suggested. However, I have placed again my css into GitHub -https://github.com/gabrielburcea/stackoverflow_fake_data/blob/master/style.css - probably you can spot differences between yours and mine?